# I Don't Have Enough Reputation to Comment

Tags: support, comments, reputation

I am not very good at golfing by myself, but once in a while, I come across something small that I notice that could help. These are typically tricks I have found while looking at tips. Some users would not think of these, as some are very strange. I would like to comment, but I do not have 50 reputation yet. I know that editing is not a good idea here, so what should I do?

Comment: In addition to the answer from Dennis, you can combine that with answering a `tips` question for the particular language. http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tips

Comment: Good job on earning the 50 reputation! Now you can comment!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Comments requiring reputation is an unfortunate situation, but it is (sadly) necessary to prevent comment spam. There is no manual override; the only way to post comments is to earn the 50 reputation points it requires.

There are a few ways to achieve this. You might already be familiar with them, but I'll list them anyway.

- Post answers. You might not be very good at golfing *right now*, but we all weren't at some point. Just tackle a few easier challenges first, and you'll see that you improve quickly. Since every upvote earns you **+10**, gathering 50 rep should be pretty quick.
- Post challenges. For most of us, that's actually *harder* than posting answers, but if you post the in [the sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges) first, the community can help you to improve your draft.
- Earn **200** rep on any single SE site. Once you do, you'll get a **+100** association bonus on all other sites.

Comment: Or have 25 edit suggestions approved. 5 answer upvotes/10 question upvotes/50 rep in bounties/25 suggested edits.

Comment: @EriktheGolfer careful with recommending edit suggestions. Posts should be edited for clarity and format, but code should not be edited, it should be commented on. And the latter is precisely what OP wants to do.

Comment: If only this question counted

Comment: @LevelRiverSt I said 25 edit suggestions *approved*. It is a measure. Of course I do not recommend edit suggestions to total newbies. And, if they edit code, they will be rejected.

Answer (score 8):

Any user with [20 rep](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/chat) on their parent site can suggest an improvement to an answer by pinging the OP [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/240/the-nineteenth-byte) and posting the suggestion there, or a link to a [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) or something if it's long.

You can also try to find the user's chat profile and invite them to some other room you're already in, or you can create a new room for a conversation between the two of you. http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/

[image]

This is a temporary solution you can use until you gain enough reputation to post comments, because comments are usually preferred to chat messages unless that question or answer is being actively discussed in chat.

Comment: I believe you need 25 rep to use the chat, but that should not be a problem for the OP

Comment: I will do this until I get 50 reputation, thanks.

Comment: @1000000000 Perhaps, but not on the specific site, so you'd only need 25 rep on *any* site. I can chat on other sites that I don't have rep on (the 100 rep for being trusted on other sites doesn't count towards requirements). If you could find a reference for that 25 rep requirement so I can link it, that'd be great.

Comment: Chat privilege is [earned at 20](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/chat), and is the same for both beta and graduated sites.

Comment: @Geobits Hmm. It says rep on the parent site is required. So I guess in that case, the 100 must count towards it, otherwise I wouldn't have been able to chat where I did.

Comment: You have *one* parent site (defined in your chat profile, initially set to the first site you registered on), no matter in which chat room you are or to which SE site that chat room belongs.

Comment: @Dennis It says "Your reputation on chat is the same as your reputation on the parent site", which is confusing wording, then. Maybe it should say "*your* parent site".

Comment: I wouldn't recommend this. The 50 rep comment limitation is there for a reason, it should not be circumvented. Chat is not a place for comments.

Comment: @EriktheGolfer Sure it is. I've had people recommend golfing improvements in chat before. Read the description of what chat is for on TNB. "General discussion for codegolf.stackexchange.com"

Comment: @mbomb007 I don't think that belongs to general discussion, but it might just be my perspective on that (yes I have a different perspective than most people).

Comment: @EriktheGolfer It's more on-topic than much other chat in TNB.